# Display org.json.JSONArray object in Dojo Grid

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I wrote a servlet to fetch data from server, adding it to JSONObject and returning that JSONObject to Dojo `request.get()` function. I am receiving the data successfully but don't know how to display that `json`.

Here is my `request.get()` function:

```
request.get("FilenetDojoServlet", {
                sync: true,  
                timeout: 3000, 
                handleAs: "json"
                }).then(function(data){

                data4 = json.stringify(data);

                console.log("Data from server : "+data4); //displaying json string of data.
                console.log("List from data : "+data4.osList); //should display "osList" contained within data

});
```

And this is what I am getting in console:

```
Data from server : {"map":{"osList":{"myArrayList":["UDMS","EBILLING","BATELCO"]}}}

List from data : undefined
```

How can I fetch values from `myArrayList` in `json` string?
I tried like this:

```
var data4 = data.map.osList.myArrayList
```

but failed!

This is the *stringified* JSON data:

```
 {"map":{"osList":{"myArrayList":["UDMS","EBILLING","BATELCO"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert a JSON string into an object. At the moment if you try `typeof data4` it should return "string", but you want an object.</del>

Dojo automatically decodes JSON for you. (There appears to have been confusion about what the OP wanted.)

Comment: I tried it 2 ways. I converted data to string using `var data4 = json.stringify(data)`, then converted to JSON object using `json.parse(data4)`, and I am still getting List as `undefined`

Other way was to convert data directly yo JSON object as `json.parse(data)` but then I am getting this error:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki I mean replace `JSON.stringify(data)` with `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Yes I tried that and now I amgetting this error: 
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki Can you `console.log(data)` and paste in what you get?

Comment: Yes with `console.log(data)` I am getting this `Object { map: Object }`
And I have updated post mentioning the stringified data as well

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki `console.log(data.map)`?

Comment: Yes now I got this `Object { osList: Object }`.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki What about `console.log(data.map.osList.myArrayList)`?

Comment: Yes got the array list items but this is not in JSON format?!

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki Dojo automatically decodes the JSON for you.

Comment: I am trying to use it in a grid. My other question would be on how to use an array in dojo grid while defining the structure of the grid?

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki Sorry I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: ok. Well thanx for your help and regarding grid, I will post another question